# How can i create an array and auto populate the elements in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

lets say i have an array :

`@time = qw(
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
);`

but the values `1..50` depend on the size of an array @arr

so instead of declaring `@time` manually, how can i populate `@time` with `1 .. @arr`, and possibly have other TYPES of elements like TIME in seconds, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by 'other types of elements'?  How would you determine the values of the other types?

Comment: I suspect you mean $#arr (which gives the index of the last element in the array), although you might also mean @arr (which in scalar context gives you the size of the array, i.e. one greater than the index of the last element in the list). I'm pretty sure you *don't* mean @#arr, which AFAIK isn't valid Perl syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will initialise `@time` with the values from `1` to `$#arr`:

```
@time = (1..$#arr);
```

I suspect you probably want `0 .. $#arr` rather than `1 .. $#arr`?

> and possibly have other TYPES of elements like TIME in seconds, etc.

I'm not quite sure what you mean here, but you should have a look at [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) for one convenient way of generating a list of values by transforming another list. That might be what you're after.

Comment: Nice to see $#arr borking the syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow just like it does in every text editor I've ever used. :-)

Comment: you should use Emacs then :-D

Comment: try Emacs.  GNU Emacs 23 highlights `$#array` just fine.  I've never tried [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/), but I expect it would handle that too.

Comment: Well, when I said "every text editor I've ever used" I was exaggerating just a little. TextMate actually handles this admirably. I'm proud to say that I adhere strongly to the laziness principle of Perl developers and hence have never bothered to learn how to use emacs. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
@time = 1 .. @arr;
```

If you want to do something with each number, like multiply them by 2, you can use `map`:

```
@time = map { 2 * $_ } 1 .. @arr;
```